# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended and ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am trying to read TYPE_ID where DESCRIPTION matches the Type. And I am using hibernate.

```
String readType = "SELECT TYPE_ID FROM TYPE_MASTER WHERE TYPE='OS' AND DESCRIPTION LIKE'%"+Type+"%'";
Query osResults = session.createSQLQuery(readType);
```

For above code I am getting error like below,

```
WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2) SQL Error: 933, SQLState: 42000
ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2) ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

[STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2) org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!

[STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)  at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:72)

[STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)  at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createSQLQuery(SessionImpl.java:1774)

[STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)  at com.usm.job.UpdateNodeInfoTable.execute(UpdateNodeInfoTable.java:54)

[STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)  at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)

[STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2)  at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
```

If I add ";" at the end of readOsType as below,

```
String readType = "SELECT TYPE_ID FROM TYPE_MASTER WHERE TYPE='OS' AND DESCRIPTION LIKE'%"+Type+"%';";
```

then I get error as below

```
WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5) SQL Error: 911, SQLState: 42000
ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5) ORA-00911: invalid character

ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5) org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)

ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)

ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2536)

ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)

ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)

ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:316)

ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1842)

ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)

ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:157)

ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)    at com.usm.job.UpdateNodeInfoTable.execute(UpdateNodeInfoTable.java:55)

ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)

ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5)    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
```

Comment: For Query with semicolon ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5) ORA-00911: invalid character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String readType = "SELECT TYPE_ID FROM TYPE_MASTER WHERE TYPE='OS' AND DESCRIPTION LIKE'%"+Type+"%' ";
Query osResults = session.createQuery(readType);
```

Replacing createSQLQuery by createQuery solved the exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have added the ';', you have SQLGrammarException which means your query is not correct. If you check your query you will see there is not space between LIKE and ', try with this:

```
String readType = "SELECT TYPE_ID FROM TYPE_MASTER WHERE TYPE='OS' AND DESCRIPTION LIKE '%"+Type+"%' ";
```